# How to remove country and city names from a MapKit map?

Tags: swift, mkmapview, mapkit

I am using `MapKit`. I'm trying to remove all country and city names from the map.

```
theMapView.removeOverlays(overlays)
```

or

```
theMapView.showsPointsOfInterest = false
```

didn't work.

Comment: did you found any solution?

Comment: @Abdel unfortunately no.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you just cant :( Apple don't allow developers to customize their MKMapView. Instead you can use other SDK like [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) or [Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/)

Comment: That simply isn't true. You can even use googlemaps as the background in MapKit, replacing Apple's maps. Check out `MKTileOverlay.canReplaceMapContent`.